# How to reference mailer component of symfony 4.3 with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony4, fosuserbundle

I would like to send my FOSUserBundle emails via the Symfony's [new mailer component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/mailer.html).

Given [these](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/emails.html) instructions, I need to create a service that implements the FOSUserBundle MailerInterface. Thus I created a service and implemented the methods.

```
<?php


namespace App\Service;

// some use statements 

class FOSUserSendgridMailer implements MailerInterface
{...
```

Now I want to reference this new service in the fos_user_yaml by:

```
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
  firewall_name: main
  service:
    mailer: App\Service\FOSUserSendgridMailer
```

I then get an error `The service "fos_user.listener.email_confirmation" has a dependency on a non-existent service "App\Service\FOSUserSendgridMailer".`

**Autowire** and **autoconfigure** are both set to `true` in `services.yaml`.

How do I reference my new service correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define it as a service in services.yaml like this:

```
App\Service\FOSUserSendgridMailer:
    class: App\Service\FOSUserSendgridMailer
```